# How to get sizes of each folder in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to find sizes for each folder in Python and this is my code. But the number of sizes that I got is different from the real size of the folder. Although I searched other posts, I was unable to find a method. Please let me know if you notice any error in my code! Thanks.

```
import os
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('#file directory')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

rootDir = '#folder location'

size = 0
row = 0

for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    worksheet.write(row, 0, '%s' % dirName)
    for f in fileList:
        fp = os.path.join(dirName, f)
        size = os.path.getsize(fp)
        worksheet.write(row, 1, '%s' % size)
    row += 1

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that getsize() is returning incorrect values?

Comment: what you mean by different? Can you give an example. (e.g. size output by your script vs size displayed in the file properties)

Comment: yes that is correct. That number is different and it is not the sum of size. There is an answer below and thank you so much take a look at my question. Since I'm not familiar with comments, I checked this out recently. Wishing you a wonderful day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like OP is trying to add the total size of all files in a directory to the spreadsheet. Therefore:

```
import xlsxwriter
from os import walk
from os.path import getsize, join

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('foo.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

rootDir = 'youngs_directory'

try:
    for row, (dirName, _, fileList) in enumerate(walk(rootDir)):
        worksheet.write(row, 0, dirName)
        size = sum(getsize(join(dirName, f)) for f in fileList)
        worksheet.write(row, 1, f'{size}')
finally:
    workbook.close()
```

Comment: Many thanks! It solved my problem and I really appreciate this. I never knew that I used for in wrong term. I will study more. I hope you have a wonderful day and thank you again!