# Please help me in getting the output I want

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

```
local = f"/home/server/Desktop/backupdestination/{year}/{month}/{date}/"
def a():
    size=0
    for root, dir_, files in os.walk(local):
      for f in dir_:
        fp = os.path.join(root, f)
        size += os.path.getsize(fp)
    print(f" DATE {date} SERVER 1 Size is {size} " )
```

This gives me output like this , (8192)this is the combination of two folder)

```
DATE 26 SERVER 1 Size is 8192
```

I want the output to be like this(4096 is file size)

```
DATE 26 SERVER 1 Size is [foldername:4096 ,foldername: 4096]
```

Comment: Do you mean concatenated in to one line?

Comment: What code have you tried to get the output you want?

Comment: @PKCS12 , Yes! DATE 26 SERVER 1 Size is [folder1:4096 ,folder2: 4096] , like this

Comment: There are no variables *date* or *local* in your code. Are you sure that calling os.path.getsize() on a directory is really what you want? I suspect what you really want is the total size of a directory's contents which, oddly enough, is the exactly same question that was asked a couple of days ago. You may find this useful:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401958/how-to-get-sizes-of-each-folder-in-python/72402186#72402186

Comment: @AlbertWinestein , lets ignore DATE variable now , I want the output to be like this
```DATE 26 SERVER 1 Size is [folder1:4096 ,folder2: 4096]``` from this ```DATE 26 SERVER 1 Size is 8192```

Comment: What code have you tried to get the output you want?

Comment: @quamrana , i could not come with code , i am strugllng on this , so i am asking for help

Comment: But there must be something you could code. For instance, what is this `folder1:4096`? Where does that come from and could you just print that out now even if it doesn't yet look right?

Comment: @quamrana ```DATE 26 SERVER 1 Size is 8192``` , this is my current output (8192 is combination of 2folders)
I want output to be like this ```DATE 26 SERVER 1 Size is [folder1name4096 ,foldername: 4096]```

Comment: Yeah, just asking the same question over and over doesn't make me any more likely to just write your code for you. At the moment I can't tell whether you've put any effort into this question at all. If you've written this code yourself, you should be able to modify it at least a little bit and print out folder names.

Comment: @quamrana , i could not come with code , i am strugllng on this , so i am asking for help
Please help

Comment: What's wrong with adding `print(fp)` to your existing code?

Comment: @quamrana ,/home/server/Desktop/backupdestination/2022/05/26/client2 , iit gives the whole dir , i just want 'client2' to be printed

Comment: Ok, yes, I see that. So try `print(f)` instead.

Comment: The reason you're getting 8192 is that you are summing the value returned by os.path.getsize() for every directory in the current list of directories returned by os.walk()

Comment: Oh , i get it
```DATE 26 SERVER 1 Size is client14096
 DATE 26 SERVER 1 Size is client24096```
How can i add both the sentences?
Like
```DATE 26 SERVER 1 Size is client1 4096 Size is client2 4096```

Comment: I used , end ='' , but still not getting it

Comment: Ok, so this is the next step. Do you know about lists in python? Have you thought about capturing the 'foldername:size' part as a string and storing it in a list?

Comment: list1 = [f] , like this?

Comment: Ok, I think I've tormented you enough. No, I meant creates a list before the `for` loop, say, `sizes = []` and then for each folder append something to the list. I've tried: `sizes.append(f'{f}:{os.path.getsize(fp)}')`. I'll provide and answer with what I've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this code:

```py
import os

def a(local):
    sizes = []
    for root, dir_, files in os.walk(local):
        for f in dir_:
            fp = os.path.join(root, f)
            size = os.path.getsize(fp)
            sizes.append(f'{f}:{size}')

    print(f" DATE SERVER 1 Size is [{','.join(sizes)}] " )

a('.')
```

Sample output:

```
DATE SERVER 1 Size is [BG2:0,collatz:0,DragonTurtle:4096,Finance:0,FindBuild38:4096]
```